# check if the youtube video is paused

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I have a video youtube embed in my website.

I want to know if anybody can show me how to check if the video is paused. Here is my code:

```
<img id="imageVideo" src="assets/img/landingpage-videothumbnail02.jpg" 
         data-video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mm9DZTC0ipk?autoplay=1" alt="" width="100%" height="274px" />
```

This is the script that when the image is clicked, then the video is played:

```
$('#imageVideo').click(function(){
    video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
    $(this).replaceWith(video);
});
```

Here is what I have been trying to check if the video is paused:

```
var paused = $("iframe .html5-main-video").paused;
    if(paused)
        {
            alert ("it is paused");
        }
```

That is because when I inspect the element, the video of youtube has a class of html5-main-video.

But it doesn't alert the function.

Help, please. Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Events

Comment: I am not using API here. Should I use API. The video is working fine without the API.

Comment: Go work with the api, there is a good introduction and examples ;)